# QUT Beamer Template (Overleaf)

Tags: beamer, babel, templates, overleaf, spanish

I found in Overleaf a quite good beamer template. However, I need to write in Spanish, and even though I added the package `\usepackage[spanish]{babel}`, when I write the outcome is not what must be:

[image: It should be Modelos Atómicos]

The project has a complicated .sty file. I´ve tried to look for some guide of how to use this template, but I did not find anything. Here is the link to the project on overleaf: https://www.overleaf.com/read/txpdhmwvkdpp.

Comment: Comment out command "\UseRawInputEncoding"

Comment: @Ignasi That fixed the issue of the Spanish spelling, but it creates three additional problems (via warnings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is the project does not compile in Overleaf.

Without modifying the preamble or the .sty I was able to get the right result (using pdflatex)  by correcting two frames, because they included characters not recognized by `inputenc`.

**(1)** In `\footnote{If containing text in equations, use $\backslash$mathrm\{\} or $\backslash$text\{\}}}` between `equation` and `use`. (line 112)

[image: e]

**(2)** In `Check definition of Equation~(\ref{eq:vsphere})  in Table~\ref{tab:number} \end{lstlisting}` after `Table~\ref{tab:number}`

It can be seen in Overleaf at the end of the line 298.

[image: d]

[image: a]

[image: b]

[image]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

% Cannot enable in Xelatex
\usepackage{pgfpages}
% \setbeameroption{hide notes} % Only slides
% \setbeameroption{show only notes} % Only notes
% \setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

% other packages
\usepackage{latexsym,amsmath,xcolor,multicol,booktabs,calligra}
\usepackage{graphicx,listings,stackengine}

%% Enable only in Xelatex
% \usepackage{pstricks}

\author{Presenter}
\title{Modelos atómicos}
\subtitle{Presentation}
\institute [School of Information Systems, QUT] {School of Information Systems\\Queensland University of Technology}
\date{\today}
\usepackage{QUT}

% defs
\def\cmd#1{\texttt{\color{red}\footnotesize $\backslash$#1}}
\def\env#1{\texttt{\color{blue}\footnotesize #1}}
\definecolor{deepblue}{rgb}{0,0,0.5}
\definecolor{deepred}{rgb}{0.6,0,0}
\definecolor{deepgreen}{rgb}{0,0.5,0}
\definecolor{halfgray}{gray}{0.55}

\lstset{
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\small,
    keywordstyle=\bfseries\color{deepblue},
    emphstyle=\ttfamily\color{deepred},    % Custom highlighting style
    stringstyle=\color{deepgreen},
    numbers=left,
    numberstyle=\small\color{halfgray},
    rulesepcolor=\color{red!20!green!20!blue!20},
    frame=shadowbox,
}


\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \titlepage
        \begin{figure}[htpb]
            \begin{center}
                \includegraphics[width=5cm]{pic/QUT.png}
            \end{center}
        \end{figure}
        
        \begin{note}
            {Introduce your self}
        \end{note}
        
    \end{frame}


\begin{frame}{Formatting Samples}
    \begin{exampleblock}{Equation without numbers} 
        \begin{equation*}
            J(\theta) = \mathbb{E}_{\pi_\theta}[G_t] = \sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}} d^\pi (s)V^\pi(s)=\sum_{s\in\mathcal{S}} d^\pi(s)\sum_{a\in\mathcal{A}}\pi_\theta(a|s)Q^\pi(s,a)
        \end{equation*}
    \end{exampleblock}          
      \begin{exampleblock}{Multiple equations\footnote{If containing text in equations, use $\backslash$mathrm\{\} or $\backslash$text\{\}}}       
        \begin{align}
            Q_\mathrm{target}&=r+\gamma Q^\pi(s^\prime, \pi_\theta(s^\prime)+\epsilon)\\
            \epsilon&\sim\mathrm{clip}(\mathcal{N}(0, \sigma), -c, c)\nonumber
        \end{align}
    \end{exampleblock}
\end{frame}


\begin{frame}[fragile]
    \begin{columns}
        \column{.6\textwidth}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=TeX]
\begin{table}[htbp]
  \caption{Definition}
  \label{tab:number}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cl}
    \toprule
    Word & Definition \\
    \midrule
    1 & 4.0 \\
    2 & 3.7 \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
Check definition of 
 Equation~(\ref{eq:vsphere})  
 in Table~\ref{tab:number}
\end{lstlisting}
        \column{.4\textwidth}
        \begin{table}[htpb]
            \centering
            \caption{Definition}
            \label{tab:number}
            \begin{tabular}{cl}\toprule
                Eq. & Def. \\\midrule
                1 & 4.0\\
                2 & 3.7\\\bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
        \normalsize Please check the definition of Equation~(\ref{eq:vsphere}) in Table~\ref{tab:number}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```